# Windows Server App Fabric Environment setup on SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, configuration, environment, appfabric, web-farm

I have One SQL Database server, two WFE and one APP server. I have planned to install windows app fabric server for caching mechanism. What is the best approach to install app fabric servers for my environment?

should it install on all WFE or only on APP server ?

Answer (score 0):

The Intention of having App Fabric Cache server installation is to increase the performance and the response time of the application or the service. SO, I would recommend to have it installed separately.